# The xcopy command that was running before is not working now in power shell

Tags: powershell, xcopy

Be sure, thecommand below was working one year ago

set source=C:\Users\sinan.almac\OneDrive - Terrafile\EKOL

set destination=\uzyttn\Excel\EKOL

xcopy %source% %destination% /y

her is the error message :

> Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Terrafile\EKOL'.
> At line:1 char:1

- set source=C:\Users\sinan.almac\OneDrive -Terrafile\EKOL
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
  ```

Cold you help me?

Comment: your `set` command has a space in the path. from what little i recall of BAT/CMD stuff, paths with embedded spaces require quoting.

Comment: I did some research about it

I tried this one 
set source="C:\Users\sinan.almac\OneDrive - Terrafile\EKOL"

set destination="\\uzyttn\Excel\EKOL"
xcopy %source% %destination% /y




it says :

File not found - %source%
0 File(s) copied

Comment: why are you running this in a powershell console? the `%EnvironmentVariable%`  you are using ONLY works in BAT/CMD ... not in powershell.

Comment: oh I see. yes I tried as a bat file . and it is worked . thankyou so much

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]